# Append/add sum to list

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to append or add the sum of iterables through a range to an empty list. I was able to do it using a for loop:

```py
list=[]
list_2=[]
def clique(n):
    for i in range(n):
        list.append(i)
        list_2=sum(list)
print clique(4)
```

but everytime I try to do it within a function I get this error:

> TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got list.

the outputs is:

> None

Comment: I'm confused. First you say you're getting a TypeError, then you say the program runs but outputs the wrong result. Which is it?

Comment: I apologize.  It outputs "None"

Comment: What do you expect it to output?

Comment: You're not returning anything from `clique`, so `print clique(4)` will always print `None`. `return` whatever object you want to print from `clique`.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `print some_function()`, the output is the return value of the function. If the function has no `return` statement, the return value is `None` by default. This is why `print clique(4)` prints `None`.

If you want `print clique(4)` to show the contents of `list`, then return `list`.

```
def clique(n):
    for i in range(n):
        list.append(i)
        list_2=sum(list)
    return list
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
list=[]

def clique(n):
    for i in range(n):
        list.append(i)
        list_2=sum(list)
    print 'list', list
    print 'list_2', list_2
clique(4)
```